# Is it possible to disable Samba user enumeration?

Tags: security, smb

It has recently been brought to my attention that you can list all samba users anonymously via [`rpc`](http://carnal0wnage.attackresearch.com/2007/07/enumerating-user-accounts-on-linux-and.html) or [`nmap`](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/smb-enum-users.html) e.g.

```
nmap --script smb-enum-users.nse ipaddress 
...
Host script results:
| smb-enum-users: 
|   Local\user0 (RID: 1000)
|     Full name:   UserName
|     Description: 
|     Flags:       Normal user account
|   Local\user1 (RID: 1001)
|     Full name:   
|     Description: 
|_    Flags:       Normal user account
```

I tried setting the following in my `smb.conf`

```
winbind enum users = no
```

With no effect. Further reading suggest that the above setting is only for actual domain accounts through winbind (which makes sense after reading more about it). All of our users are local Samba users. From what I can tell `nmap` and `rpc` are using the enum-users and enum-groups feature in the SMB RPC interface. [I have found a decent amount of information on how to exploit it](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/scanner-smb-auxiliary-modules/) but is there anyway to disable it?

I am currently running the most current version in the CentOS repos - `samba-3.6.23-35.el6_8.x86_64`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this share to `smb.conf` disabled all user/share enumeration.

```
[ipc$]
hosts allow = 127.0.0.1
hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0
guest ok = no
browseable = no
```